# create/extract svg image from xml data

Tags: c#, svg

I have received XML node that contains SVG data (part of rules for GIS OSM data) as following:

```
    <svg:symbol id="synagogue" viewBox="0 0 20 20" stroke="#0000d0" fill="none" stroke-width="1.5px" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter">
        <svg:path d="M 10,0 L 20,15 L 0,15 L 10,0 z M 10,20 L 0,5 L 20,5 L 10,20 z"/>
    </svg:symbol>
```

How can i convert this data to SVG image ? I download a library SvgDocument (for C#) and successfully used it, but the format of this certain node, I cant convert it.. What is the "d" attribute data ?

E.g of files i successfully converted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="20" height="20" id="symbol-parking-private">
<rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="19" height="19" rx="2" ry="2" style="stroke:#aaaaaa;stroke-width:1;fill:#ffffff" />
<path d="M4,17 L4,3 10,3 C14,3 16,5 16,7.5 C16,10 14,12 10,12 L8.5,12 8.5,17 z M8.5,9 L10,9 C13,9 13,6 10,6 L8.5,6 8.5,9 z" style="stroke-width:0;fill:#aaaaaa" />
</svg>
```

Comment: The "d" attribute data, is the data that gives the svg moves, you can draw whatever you want with a path + d attribute.

To convert your xml node, you just need to convert your <svg:path to simple <path.

Comment: ok, this is what i had missing, to take the :path and place it as the node name and then d is the attribute. thanks

Comment: exactly, I already did the job with svg conversions, I recently got lots of xml from openstreetmap too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove all `svg:` prefixes
2. `symbol` must be enclosed in `defs`, then it can be used with `use`

see http://jsfiddle.net/5ac52gs6/1/

btw. your `symbol viewBox` cuts some parts of the symbol (you have to pay the attention to `stroke-width`)